# EventLogAppender: questionable "fix" property

Tags: log4net

Currently reviewing the log4net configs we have and found our eventlog appender like so:

```
<appender name="EventLog" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender">
  <fix value="None" /> <!-- performance boost -->
  [... etc ...]
</appender>
```

However, the only reference to this "fix" property I can find is from [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319319/log4net-bufferingforwardingappender-performance-issue) about the `BufferingForwardingEventHandler` where setting the value to "None" is shown to yield performance improvements.

Also [the docs on EventLogAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Appender_EventLogAppender.htm) do not list such a property, like [the docs on BufferingForwardingEventHandler](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Appender_BufferingForwardingAppender.htm).

So is this property simply meaningless for the `EventLogAppender` or does it serve some potentially undocumented function here as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's meaningless. There's no reference to [FixFlags](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4net/blob/master/src/Core/LoggingEvent.cs#L208) anywhere in the [source for EventLogAppender](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4net/blob/master/src/Appender/EventLogAppender.cs).

It only appears [in BufferingAppenderSkeleton](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4net/blob/master/src/Appender/BufferingAppenderSkeleton.cs#L254), as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for also having a look. Many eyes and all. Will remove it and see if it makes any difference.